# What to add at zipFile to avoid Invalid method declaration: method type required exception in Java?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    zipFIle appZip = new zipFIle();
    appZip.generateFileList(new File(SOURCE_FOLDER));
    appZip.zipIt(OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE);
}


 zipFIle() {
    fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

This logic is throwing invalid method declaration: method type required. May I know what shoud I add at zipFIle method?

Comment: `zipFIle` That's an extreme ugly name for a class. I advise you to go through a basic tutorial my friend.

Comment: Can you please tell `zipFIle`  is a method or a  Class ? Ofcourse your declaration is wrong for any.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ It's a class as he's declaring `appZip` to be of that type..

Comment: zipFIle() is a method for that which return type i have to add?

Comment: Have you tried File type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `zipFIle()` is a method (and not a constructor), then you need to add a return type. If you don't want to return anything, use `void`:

```
void zipFIle() {
  fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

You may also wish to add an access modifier (`public`, `protected` or `private`) if the default access level is not correct.

However... your other code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    zipFIle appZip = new zipFIle();
    appZip.generateFileList(new File(SOURCE_FOLDER));
    appZip.zipIt(OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE);
}
```

... suggests `zipFIle` is a class name. So... I'm going to guess this is perhaps a constructor you are writing? If so, you shouldn't declare any return type and your existing code ought to work, unless you've not included it in a class file:

```
public class zipFIle {

  private final List<String> fileList;

  zipFIle() {
    fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
  }

  private void generateFileList(File file) {
    // whatever...
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    zipFIle appZip = new zipFIle();
    appZip.generateFileList(new File(SOURCE_FOLDER));
    appZip.zipIt(OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE);
  }
}
```

Final note: `zipFIle` is a horrible name for a method or a class. If it is a class name, use `TitleCase`. If it's a method name, use `camelCase`.